Ms Access VBA - Interface - user defined Type not defined upon implements
trying to use interfaces in ms access vba but i get this error:

This is the code for ITest:
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "ITest"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Property Get ParentForm() As Form

End Property

selecting the interface with the dropdown to implement it, results in the above error.
When manually typing the expected property, the same error occurs.
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Class1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Implements ITest


Private Property Get ITest_ParentForm() As Form

End Property

This is a new blank file.
I expected this to be straightforward and simple but something is wrong here.
When commenting out all the code, the error persists upon compile.
The references of this project:

Office Version:
Microsoft® Access® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2404 Build 16.0.17531.20190) 64-bit
Edit:
my IT guy reinstalled office, but the issue persists....

I can't reproduce this using the code in the question, it works fine for me (as it should, the code is valid). Could you export ITest to a file and look for hidden properties? No odd stuff in references that may cause a name conflict?

Thanks for checking it @ErikA. I add the export to the question.

Odd, these seem valid, and the references? You can sometimes get this error if you have a reference to an invalid VBA project, and these can get added by default. If that's the case, the erroring code is actually unrelated to the shared code.

I added the references and the office version.
Maybe I should try to repair office.

Well, consider me lost, that's all standard and I can't reproduce this on version 2308. You could perhaps get similar behavior by messing with the default Access add-ins (office folder/accwiz/UTILITY.ACCDA for example), but that seems highly unlikely as these are part of the Office install.

You could try the 'Clean this project' function of VBE_Extras ... download/install then right-click the project name in the Project Window, select Extras > Clean this project ... backup first! (full disclosure: I am the author of VBE_Extras ... but you can try it for free!) ... no guarantee of fixing your problem as it isn't clear exactly what is wrong, but might be worth a try.

@JohnM unfortunately I do not have the freedom to install any software I would like to try. I check back with the IT department and try to figure out if this might be related to the installation of office itself or some it group policy.
I tried to repair office myself but it seems like it does nothing on ms access.

Common corruption issue usually when renaming types. Create a new db and import everything from the old - that should fix the problem.

@KostasK. I created a  new db and typed the code. There was nothing renamed.

Decompiling the access file removes the problem.
It's explained here: How does one decompile and recompile a database application?
But it does not fix the cause. I.e. I can get the access file into this state again.
